# Compile error when I use playpen.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I learn c++

I try to do everything on this link
https://code.google.com/archive/p/youcandoit/downloads

but I have a problem here

[image: here]

Does anyone have an idea of what the playpen.h is and how to fix it?

```
inline istream & operator >> (istream & in , hue & shade){
    shade = (std::cin == in ? fgw::read<int>() : fgw::read<int>(in));
    return in;
```

error occurs here: ==

Comment: What is that method trying to achieve? The error indicates that you're trying to compare two std::istream objects, but they're not comparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There just isn't an `==` operator comparing two streams. To check for identity you normally compare the addresses of the object, like `if (&in == &std::cin)`.

On the other hand, `cin` is an `istream` so `fgw::read<int>(in)` ought to work even when `in` is `cin`.